# What kind of error to throw on Http Service

Tags: xml, http, exception, mule

I'm working on `Mule 3.3.0` application and there are message listeners on 2 inbound endpoints. One endpoint is exposing a `Soap service` and other is a `Http Service`. I throw `Soap Fault` on exception conditions on Soap service endpoint. I'm wondering what kind of exception (exception structure) can be thrown when error occurs on Http Service.

It doesn't seem right to me to throw `Soap Fault` on Http Service. This service is expected to receive input request in `XML` format.

Comment: Please comment to help me improve post when you downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick [error status codes from the ones HTTP support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) to best represent the nature of the errors.

You can also add a body entity to the HTTP response to further detail the error. If the client of the HTTP service deals with XML message, use an XML representation too.

Comment: Thanks David. Something on lines of this [xml example](http://dev.bitly.com/formats.html). My confusion is _Are there any standard set of tags that can be used to define output xml_ or whatever I feel like and client will do custom parsing?

Comment: Please, **do not follow the bitly error model**: they return `200` for all responses, even the erroneous ones, forcing to dig in the XML to find the status code. Use real response status codes and whatever format you want to the response entity, if you use one. Just be consistent with the XML schema used for successful responses.